# Problem in downloading sdks using sdkmanager

Tags: 17.04, android-sdk

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while and it's getting on my last nerve.
I'm trying to download android sdk packages through `sdkmanager` but every time I try to do it an error message pops up and I can't download the requested  packages here's every thing that is written on my terminal:

```
mahmood@mahmood-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ cd AndroidSDK/android_sdk/tools/bin/
mahmood@mahmood-Lenovo-B50-30:~/AndroidSDK/android_sdk/tools/bin$ ./sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Warning: File /home/mahmood/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: Failed to parse source list at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
Warning: Failed to find package platforms;android-26
```

Could somebody please help me solve this problem so I can download the  required sdks ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Reagankm sadly no. After encountering similar problems on Ubuntu I had to switch to Windows again.